# Does Windows support Linux-style paths?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

Let's say I only have drive C, and I have a directory in it called `Something`.

I can use `cmd` to navigate to it via `cd C:\Something`.

But I realized that `cd /Something` also does the same thing.

I also realized that I can use `/Something/app.exe` inside my `script.bat` file and it gets executed.

And I also realized that these lines of codes work fine inside Visual Studio:

```
<Import Project="C:\Something\Base.targets" />
<Import Project="/Something/Base.targets" />
```

It seems to me that I can use Linux-style paths inside Windows.

However, I tried IIS with this method and it failed.

So, why this path convention works in other parts in Windows? Does Windows support it? If it supports it then why IIS fails to understand it?

Comment: Per the duplicate, it boils down to *how* the application handles the paths and whether they use Windows APIs in a way that just lets Windows abstract out the difference.